# Gradle build failing : Task 'jar' not found in root project 'spotify-web-api-android'

Tags: gradle, gradlew

I am trying to use the 'spotify-web-api-android' library by compiling and building a jar. Instructions to generate the jar have been provided, but are failing for me.

- **What I want** : Build the jar file successfully
- **What is the problem** - I am not familiar to Gradle and am getting the error : Task 'jar' not found in root project 'spotify-web-api-android'.
- **Steps followed**:

  - Downloaded spotify (see screenshot)
    [image]
  - Changed directory to the downloaded git
  - Executed command : ./gradlew jar
    [image]

**Link to api and instructions** : https://github.com/kaaes/spotify-web-api-android/blob/master/README.md

Instructions to generate jar:

1. Clone the repository: git clone https://github.com/kaaes/spotify-web-api-android.git
2. Build: ./gradlew jar
3. Grab the jar and put it in your project. It can be found in build/libs/spotify-web-api-android-0.1.0.jar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think those build instructions are out of date.

Try the `./gradlew assemble` instructions instead, using the `aar` dependency

Comment: how do we use the "aar" dependency ??

Answer (score 1):

https://androidbycode.wordpress.com/2015/02/23/building-an-aar-library-in-android-studio/

//Use this way

repositories {

```
    flatDir {
        dirs 'libs'
    }
```

}

dependencies {

```
    compile(name:'yourlibraryname', ext:'aar')
```

}